# Load plugin js files in partials and should be shown in header tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, keyboard

I'm using Mottie keyboard https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard. All the JS and CSS from this plugin added in index.html. My partial file is home.html in this file only i have keyboard code, but that was not working.
If i'm adding those CSS and JS files it was working in homepage but all the js files were rendering console also in GET method...

Below are my code.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en"  ng-app="CSI">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>AXA</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->  
    <link href="docs/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/video-css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/keyboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/css/tipsy.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/css/prettify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- project scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.keyboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-caret.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/jquery.tipsy.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/js/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/touchswipe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**home.html**

```
<input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Name"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I dont know why my code is not working... the keyboard is coming... if i add all the keyboard related scripts in home.html keyboard was coming but in browser console all the scripts are changed into GET requests and loading always whenever the page get refreshed.

**Browser console**

[image]

Any suggestion Any help.
Thankq in advance.

Comment: Try putting all the script tags inside body tag.
i.e.
<body><script></script></body>

Comment: @ManishSingh I did this but then keyborad not getting initialized. For making keyboard work i removed those scripts and added in home.html. Any other suggestion or solution. please help me out.

Comment: Will you please put the directory structure of these files?

Comment: @ManishSingh not able to update my folder structure in comment box. will tell oral about my folder structure. projectName in this 3 folders "dist, docs, public" and 3 files " index.html, home.html,profile.html ". dist and docs folders are from Mottie Keyboard (  https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard ). In public folder i have app folder in that app.js file. So this my folder structure. please give any help

Comment: Can you share your screen via teamviewer?